# Can't understand what Javadoc is

Tags: java, html, comments

I can't understand what 'Javadoc' is.
I wanted to know the difference between the `/**  */` and `/* */` comments in the first place.

When I saw the answer in here, It said something about HTML and *APIs* in java. It was totally confusing and I couldn't understand anything. I am just a beginner in Java, so please help me...

I saw that there was absolutely *NO Difference* when I used both of them. The compiler ignored both multiline comments when it was executed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Comment: @ernest_k I don't think a Wikipedia article is good for a beginner to understand something.

Comment: You really need to be patient when you start learning programming. Don't expect yourself to understand all the concepts that you run into when you learn and read on the Internet. It takes time, specifically because you need to read and understand the basics of the language and its tools; otherwise things just become overwhelming too fast, as shown by the (follow up) questions asked here.

Comment: Um, I couldn't understand what a documentation can be used for. I mean, it doesn't come to use to editors of the source code and I can't see what use it can come to viewers if they have access to the java file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc has nothing to do with the compiled code or any other runtime behaviour.

It's there so that the programmer can comment on the classes, variables and methods. All in-place, no external comments or files needed.

And when you have an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, it will show these comments when you hover over the method call somewhere else.

Javadoc can also be read from the source code (.java classes) and compiled into HTML pages, just like all major Java documentation is.

Check this out, it's a pretty good overview: https://www.baeldung.com/javadoc

Comment: I couldn't understand this part:
https://www.baeldung.com/javadoc#2-javadoc-with-maven-plugin

Comment: If you are using Maven as a build tool, then you could let Maven also generate the HTTP documentation from the Java source files. If you're not using maven, but any other build tool, then you can ignore that paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will ignore both comments, yes.  There is no difference in what the compiler does.

The difference is that you can use the Javadoc tool to turn Javadoc comments -- not normal comments -- into documentation like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html).  (Many IDEs, like Eclipse or IntelliJ, will also show documentation in this format, for example when you mouse over a method that you're calling.)

Comment: yes, but what is it's use ? The /** */ comments in used in the main() loop did not come in the documentation in blueJ

Comment: It can only be used on methods, fields, classes, etc. themselves.  It can't show anything inside a function body.  It's for users of your code to see what it does, not for editors of your code to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Normal comments get deleted when compiling to class.

Javadocs don't stay in the code just like regular comments and can be used to automatically generate HTML docs that you can publish for people to understand your API for example.


Javadoc example:
https://docs.javacord.org/api/v/3.4.0/

Comment: What does an API do in java ??

Comment: @SuperCoder 
API stands for Application Programming Interface. In the context of APIs, the word application refers to any software with a specific function. The interface can be seen as a service contract between two applications.

Example
You can import jodatime into your java project for example. After importing it you can use it's functions. There are also web based apis you can google REST api if you wanna know more

Comment: @Brentspine Are you sure that the Javadoc comments stay in the code? Can you post me a link so I can read up on it?

Comment: My bad, I thought they would stay in the .class files, but they actually do not. 
But it makes sense that they don't affect the performance

Comment: @SuperCoder https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-apis/